# Basic Authorization и MediaPlayer

Tags: mediaplayer, android

есть mp3 файл и лежит он на сервере, а так же на сервере apache простая авторизация
нужно проиграть файл в MediaPlayer
подключил библиотеку import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно правильно получить файл в mediaPlayer.setDataSource(); ?
    <code>import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent in = getIntent();
String filename = in.getStringExtra(KEY_FILENAME);

if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause){

try {
String AUDIO_PATH = "http://91.73.25.212:8080/imap/attachments/"+filename;
String username = "admin";
String password = "admin";
String userpassword = username + ":" + password;
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(userpassword.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

URL url = new URL(AUDIO_PATH);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AUDIO_PATH);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
mediaPlayer.start();
ButtonTestPlayPause.setText("PAUSE");
}else {
mediaPlayer.pause();
ButtonTestPlayPause.setText("PLAY");
}
}
}</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы логично передавать адрес в виде `http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path>`, но, к сожалению, `MediaPlayer` не поддерживает этого, о чём имеется давний репорт в багтрекере Android.

Полагаю, единственным способом решения вашей проблемы будет открытие в своём приложении локального порта (на который и будет натравливаться `MediaPlayer`), который будет перенаправлять сетевые запросы от `MediaPlayer`'а к целевому хосту, и, соответственно, передавать его ответы обратно, к `MediaPlayer`'у.

Comment: Спасибо. Решил по другому немного. Авторизовался, скачал файл в кеш, проиграл файл в MediaPlayer из кеша.